# Angular 6 - No matching service worker detected

Tags: javascript, json, angular, angular6, progressive-web-apps

Hello I am trying to add PWA functionality to an Angular 6 application, previously was working on Angular 5, so I updated, then used

> ng add @angular/pwa --project

Browser reads the manifest but throws this warning:

```
No matching service worker detected. You may need to reload the page or check that the service worker for the current page also controls the start URL from the manifest.
```

The thing is that the application is bilingual so when you access localhost it redirects you to localhost/ro or locahost/en. This is done trough **ngrx translate module**. I don't know if this may affect the scope or not or even the start url in the manifest.

Here is my manifest.json:

```
  "name": "formashefitness",
  "short_name": "formashefitness",
  "theme_color": "#1976d2",
  "background_color": "#fafafa",
  "display": "standalone",
  "scope": "/", {..}
```

Here is how I register the service worker:

```
ServiceWorkerModule.register('ngsw-worker.js', { enabled: environment.production })
```

I tried to debug by adding the following code to main.ts:

```
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule).then(() => {
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator && environment.production) {
    navigator.serviceWorker.register('ngsw-worker.js');
}
}).catch(err => console.log(err))
```

And got a 404 error the the service worker file, eventough it's there.

Comment: in your angular.json do you have "serviceWorker": true ?

Comment: yes, it was set automatically I believe when used the add pwa command.

Comment: is your "ngswConfigPath" has the correct path of the json config?

Comment: ngswConfigPath is not present in the angular.json file, but ngsw.json is present in the root folder of dist. I don't know where should that be?

Comment: the value of ngswConfigPath should be the location of your ngsw-config.json